# Javascript (node) error: Unexpected token function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

I am trying the learn younode workshop, the make it modular step to be precise. I wrote the code in the link and am getting the "error in the title". I have checked brackets and parenthesis but can not seem to find where i got it wrong. Any help would be appreciated (i just started with node).
My code is this and you can find it also at this link:
http://pastebin.com/G8x2GH7h

```
module.exports = function (directoryPath, extention, function(error, arrayOfNames) {
        var fs = require('fs');
        var path = require('path');
        var FileNamesArray = [];
        fs.readdir(directoryPath,function (error,list){
                list.forEach(function (file) {
                        if (path.extname(file) === '.' + extention) {
                                FileNamesArray.push(file);
                        }
                });
        });
        return FileNamesArray;
        }){
        return ArrayOfNames;
}
```

Comment: What is `ArrayOfNames` up to?

Comment: The `function` you have at `(directoryPath, extention, function(error, arrayOfNames)`  is a syntax error.

Comment: `function(error, arrayOfNames) {...}` is not valid where it is. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do with that.

Comment: @Armand: for the task we demand that you crate a module that would filter file names in a given directory to call it from another file and print it to the console from there.

Comment: @FelixKling: That function is creating an array containing the names of the files that have the given extesion.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are declaring function inside of function declaration.

Comment: It's perfectly valid to define functions inside other functions.

Comment: Yes, it is valid to define functions inside of other function body, but not valid to define them at position of argument in function declaration. It will give syntax error.

Comment: No, you can define an inline function as a parameter. That's the usual way when you define a callback function

Comment: You can define inline function as parameter when you are `calling` another function, not when you are `declaring` another function.

Comment: @pisamce: so according to you i should first declare my function and then pass it as an argument to the other one ?

Comment: You are right. You should be more precise in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
exports.functionName = function() {
  // your code
};
```

And then In you app.js you can use

```
var abc = require('path to file name');
abc.functionName();
```

example

```
// square.js
var PI = Math.PI;

exports.area = function (r) {
  return PI * r * r;
};

exports.circumference = function (r) {
  return 2 * PI * r;
};

// app.js
 var square = require("./square.js");

var mySquare = square(2);
console.log('The area of my square is ' + mySquare.area());
```

Remove the anonymous function inside your function and hopefully it should  work for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but according to http://liangzan.net/blog/blog/2012/06/04/how-to-use-exports-in-nodejs/ there is two different ways for the export. In the task i am give they specified that you should use the module.exports and not the exportes.function method.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the title of you function in the export section, should be in this way:

```
module.exports = {
getFileNamesList : function (directoryPath, extention, function(error, arrayOfNames) {
            var fs = require('fs');
            var path = require('path');
            var FileNamesArray = [];
            fs.readdir(directoryPath,function (error,list){
                    list.forEach(function (file) {
                            if (path.extname(file) === '.' + extention) {
                                    FileNamesArray.push(file);
                            }
                    });
            });
            return FileNamesArray;
            }){
            return ArrayOfNames;

        }
    }
```